# WPF: Add TabControl.Selected event to DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have the following XAML which sets up my **TabControl**:

```
<TabControl Name="TabsControl"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabViewModel}">

    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SystemSetupViewModel}">
            <v:SystemSetupUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RateTablesViewModel}">
            <v:RateTablesUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
        </Style>

    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</TabControl>
```

Is there a way to add a command (bind to a method in my ViewModel) to a specific tab that would allow me to execute a method each time the tab is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually approach something like this is by putting this in the ViewModel -- since you're binding to the SelectedItem, can you not check if the old value != new value, and if so, call the method?  Are your ViewModels the SelectedItem (looks to be the case) or are they declared in the View and therefore inaccessible from your current point?

If they are, then couldn't each ViewModel implement an interface, i.e. ISelectedTabCallback, and then execute the method on that?